# Remove Main Partition (C:) and make other Parition (D:) the main

Tags: windows, windows-8, hard-drive, windows-10, partitioning

Basically I installed windows 8 and windows 10 on the same HDD. I created a partition on the HDD for each. I started with windows 8 on C: and then created a partition (D:) and installed windows 10 on it. Now I want to keep windows 10 and remove 8 (on C:) but I can't delete the partition because there are boot files and paging on (C:).

What do I need to do this? I've been googling for a while with no luck.

Comment: It boots directly into windows 10 (D:) and that works great. My windows 8 partition has these words below it (Healthy, Boot, Crash Dump. Primary Partition) and my Windows 10 partition has these words (Page File, Primary Partition). I'd take a screenshot but it's on another computer without internet. My question is how do I wipe windows 8 (C:) and then delete it? Will I still be able to boot since that isn't on Win 10 (D:)?  I can't click "delete partition". It's greyed out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **Remove Main Partition (C:) and make other Parition (D:) the main**
>
> Now I want to keep windows 10 and remove 8 (on C:) but I can't delete
>   the partition because there are boot files and paging on (C:).

Use the below instructions with [gparted](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/download.php) to set the Window 10 partition as the active boot partition, confirm that it reboots properly as you would expect, and then afterwards wipe the Windows 8 disk partition from Disk Management, reformat, and so on.

> **Use a GParted Live CD to make a Linux or Windows drive Active**
>
> **How to use the free GParted CD to mark a Linux or Windows Primary
>   partition Active.**
>
> 1. Download the latest stable release of
>      [GParted](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/download.php) and create the
>      Live CD from the ISO file.
> 2. Boot from the Linux Live CD and complete
>      the three user-input requests.  GParted will run automatically.
>
>    - Right-click the Primary partition you wish to make Active  and select
>        Manage Flags.
>    - In Manage Flags on ..., tick (to enable) the boot check
>        box to make the partition Active.
>    - Click Close and exit the partition utility
> 3. Restart your computer.
>
> <sub>[source](http://thpc.info/how/make_active.html#gpart)</sub>

To burn a Live CD instructions, download the gparted ISO and then see [How to burn a DVD on Windows](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/burn-a-dvd-on-windows) for the instructions how to burn an image to a disc with Windows 10; you can use a CD rather than a DVD for gparted but the steps should be very similar regardless and self explanatory from there.

> **How to burn a DVD on Windows**
>
> Once you’ve downloaded the file, follow the instructions below to burn
>   your DVD, depending on which version of Windows you are currently
>   using.
>
> **Windows 7 / 8 / 10**
>
> 1. Right-click on an ISO image and choose '**Burn disc image**'.[image]
> 2. Select a disc burner (drive) and choose '**Burn**'. If you check '**Verify disc after burning**', it will confirm that the ISO image has been burned correctly.
>
> [image]
>
> <sub>[source](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/burn-a-dvd-on-windows)</sub>

Comment: Great thanks. This makes a lot of sense. How do you make a "Live_CD". All else seems pretty straight forward.

Comment: @DigitalMC I just added instructions to the bottom of my answer for this.

Comment: I got it installed and gpart seems to be useful, but now its saying i dont have an OS. This happened when i changed the "Page File" to windows 10 (before Gpart). Can i use gpart to move "page file" back to windows 8?